# With iTunes DJ gone from iTunes 11, what's a good replacement solution?

Tags: itunes

With iTunes DJ gone from iTunes 11, how can I go to replace or even enhance the lost functionality?

Answer (score 17):

I'm still adjusting it, but here is something that might actually be better than iTunes DJ on some aspects:

- create a playlist with some rules approaching the way you were using iTunes DJ. Something like Rating > 3, not played in a month, live update based on least played or random or whatever you were using with iTunes DJ.
- start playing
- switch to Mini Player
- turn on Up Next View and extend it vertically. You can alternatively show previously played using the clock icon.

What I like with this is the amount of interaction you have with the songs coming up. With a few clicks and remaining in that compact view, you can delete songs, add songs in the queue from genius recommendations. You can even bring up a full iTunes window on the side for drag and drop of additional songs or quick add (via alt-click) of songs to Up Next. Might take a little while to get used to it but it has potential.

[image: my iTunes DJ replacement]

Comment: One thing I really liked about iTunes DJ was the ability to play higher rated songs with a higher probability, but to still include all songs in the mix.  I think it would be possible to do this, but it would involve creating for example, five identical playlists with 5 star songs, four playlists for 4 star songs, and so on, and mix them all together, which is an awful lot of work.

Comment: I think too Up next is a pretty good alternative to iTunes DJ, and has been well integrated into Remote 3 iOS app. But @asmeurer is right, the one feature we lost in the transition is the Play higher rated songs that cannot be replaced satisfactorily. Activating this feature triggered a subtle bias that I documented [on my blog](http://kray.me/blog/daily-routine-smart-playlist-filterings/).