# How can I show the Cover Art window in iTunes 11?

Tags: album-art, itunes

I like to see the album art for each song as it comes on; in iTunes 10, I would have iTunes DJ playing, hidden under my other apps, whilst the current song's cover displayed in a floating window on my second monitor...

Can I do something similar in iTunes 11? (at the moment, I'm using the iTunes DJ replacement suggested [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73202/with-itunes-dj-gone-from-itunes-11-whats-a-good-replacement-solution), but the thumbnail is tiny!)

I've sifted through the menu and prefs, but didn't find anything.. I'm hoping that someone will have a tricky way / script that replaces my 2nd Desktop Wallpaper with the art!?

Fingers crossed, Tx!

Comment: Show the 'art' drawer under the sidebar, (choose current track or selected) and click.  The floating window can be dragged to any monitor! (Seems the same in iTunes11, but only for the current track).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get the second window back, all you have to do is click the album artwork thumbnail in the Now Playing area, either in the full version:

[image]

Or in the Mini Player

[image]

Both will pop up the larger album art view you are looking for.

In iTunes 11.0, there currently isn't the sidebar album art view that used to be there.

Comment: iTunes 12: but by click on that thumbnail, i get a 400px artwork, seriously? I want 1200px, even if I add my own artwork in 5000px, it just shows it in 400px, what did Apple screw here up? Any help?

Answer (score 1):

My mistake, I've found that from mini-view, clicking the thumbnail of the current track opens the floating viewer I was looking for.. I was fooled because iTunes 10 had the little drawer that would allow selected tracks' covers to be shown.  It seems that this view is only visible for the playing track..

Comment: That was so close! I was going to answer! Well, never mind!

Comment: Only thing I would add to your answer - you don't have to just be in mini player, the art shows up on the full one too, and works the same way.

Comment: @duci9y submit an answer, and I'll accept it! I can't accept my own answer for 2 days :)
@ jmlumpkin tx!